# FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS is not working in KitKat and above

Tags: android, android-intent, task, android-4.4-kitkat

My **Activity A** is opening **Activity B** in another task. 
I'm trying to have only one task icon in task bar/recent apps. 
**Activity B** is started with the following flags:  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK 
In OS versions < 4.4 it works and only one task is shown in the task bar. 
On OS >= KitKat you will see two icons in resent apps.

Code sample

```
    Intent activityBIntent;
    activityBIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    activityBIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(activityBIntent);
    finish();
```

**ActivityB** has affinity different than **ActivityA**:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.bla.ActivityB"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

<activity
    android:name="com.bla.ActivityA"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
</activity>
```

Any idea what can cause this? Any other workaround?

Comment: @Niz1 u got solution ?

Comment: "I'm trying to have only one task icon in task bar/recent apps." This icon should represent which task? The one containing ActivityA or ActivityB? Also you should make sure (by providing a launcher icon) that the user has a way to get back to ActivityB if he leaves it by pressing the home button.